# Is there any limit on what I can set for http.parsing.max-uri-length

Tags: akka-http

The most I've seen someone use was http.parsing.max-uri-length = 16k

I don't see anything in the akka-http project that gives that as a limit https://github.com/akka/akka-http/search?q=max-uri-length

I'm creating a new GET API endpoint, and this particular endpoint could have 400/500 parameters passed, it could get past 16k characters. Can I increase the max-uri-length to any limit I want or must I change that api endpoint to use POST where there's no real limit on data being passed?

Comment: [Look also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/8564999). Long URIs are troublesome. E.g. as stated in this link, if you'll ever wish use a service like Cloudfare to deliver your API, you won't be able to pass long URIs past it.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, won't be ever using Cloudfare. The endpoint will be behind kong for external use and behind nothing for internal server to server use.

Comment: I just mean that it's easier to put a moderate limit and thus preserve compatibility. Because otherwise later you'll possibly be scratching your head and refactoring all the code relying on long URIs